# Problema de SNMP em C#

Tags: c#, .net, snmp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que realize coletas *SNMP* em um determinado servidor. Estou utilizando a biblioteca `SnmpSharpNet`.

Estou conseguindo fazer normalmente o *snmpwalk* em uma determinada *OID*.

Porém, existe uma *OID* que lista os processos em execução do servidor, e eu consigo extrair o número do processo.

Com o número do processo, eu faço um `append` dele no final de uma outra *OID* e então realizo um `GET` para pegar o nome do processo.

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é, se caso o número do processo seja maior que determinado número, por exemplo `16535`, ele está dando um erro durante a execução dizendo que o número é grande.

Pelo que entendi do código, se o número for maior que `127` ele transforma em vários bytes:

```
// Convert the string MIB into a byte array of integer values
      // Unfortunately, values over 128 require multiple bytes
      // which also increases the MIB length
      for (i = 0; i < orgmiblen; i++)
      {
         temp = Convert.ToInt16(mibvals[i]);
         if (temp > 127)
         {
            mib[cnt] = Convert.ToByte(128 + (temp / 128));
            mib[cnt + 1] = Convert.ToByte(temp - ((temp / 128) * 128));
            cnt += 2;
            miblen++;
         } else
         {
            mib[cnt] = Convert.ToByte(temp);
            cnt++;
         }
      }
```

E eu não consegui uma forma de fazer isso para números grandes, no caso `16535` (que é o número do processo rodando no servidor).

Alguma ideia?